# Scla/Java library not installing on execution of Databricks Notebook

Tags: scala, import, databricks, jobs, azure-databricks

At work I have a Scala Databricks Notebook that uses many libraries imports, both from Maven and from some JAR files. The issue I have is that when I plan jobs on this Notebook, it sometimes fails (completely randomly but mostly 1 time over 10 runs) because it executes the cells before all libraries are installed. Thus the job fails and I have to go launch it manually. Such comportment from this Databricks' product is far from being professional as I can't use it in production because it sometimes fails.

I tried to put a `Thread.Sleep()` of 1 minute or so before all my imports, but it does not change anything. For Python there's the `dbutils.library.installPyPI("library-name")` but there's no such thing for Scala in the Dbutils documentation.

So does anyone have had the same issue and if so, how did you solve it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put for prod scheduled jobs use `New Job Cluster` and avoid `All Purpose Cluster`.

`New Job Clusters` are dedicated clusters created and started when you run a task and terminate immediately after the task completes. In production, [Databricks recommends](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#:%7E:text=New%20Job%20Clusters%20are%20dedicated,in%20a%20fully%20isolated%20environment.) using new clusters so that each task runs in a fully isolated environment.

In the UI, when setting up your notebook job select a `New Job Cluster` and afterwards add all the dependent libraries to the job.

The pricing is different for `New Job Cluster`. I would say it ends up cheaper.

Note: [Use Databricks pools](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/instance-pools/index.html) to reduce cluster start and auto-scaling times (if it's an issue to begin with).